# Which multiple comparisons correction should I use?

Tags: correlation, multiple-comparisons

I'm studying structure-function relationships in neurons and mainly focusing on correlations between dendritic length and excitability. My question is:

**When searching for correlations, which multiple comparison correction should I use to classify which of the correlations I find are significant?**

I have measured dendrite length (apical and basal) which provided me with 3 values: apical dendrite length, basal dendrite length and total dendrite length. I've also measured 5 different electrophysiological paramaters within the same cells. My research question is: Are the electrophysiological parameters related (correlated) with the dendritic length? This yields 3×5 comparisons (3 length parameters with 5 electrophysiological). I have found some significant correlations, as expected. Now I want to find out whether the significance of these correlations must be corrected,          and if so, which method I must use. Bonferoni correction seems a little too conservative, because correlations between structure and function of a neuron seems logical, and it has already been established that they exist.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail. There are lots of possible ways to correct for multiple comparisons, each w/ different pros & cons.

Comment: Alright, I have measured dendrite length (apical and basal) which provided me with 3 values, apical dendrite length, basal dendrite length and total dendrite length. I've also measured 5 different electrophysiological paramaters within the same cells. My RQ is: Are the electrophysiological parameters related (correlated) with the dendritic length. This yields 3x5 comparisons (3 length parameters with 5 electrophysiological). I have found some significant correlations, as expected. Now i want to find out whether the significance of these correlations must be corrected.

Comment: And if so, which method i must use. Bonferoni correction seems a little too conservative because correlations between structure and function of a neuron seems logical and it has already been established that they exist.